# Matplotlib Draw Polygons of different color

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw polygons using `fill()`. How can I draw polygons of different color? It seems to me that I can only use one color. I tried a list with three color values per polygon but I keep getting this error: `length of rgba sequence should be either 3 or 4`. The only thing that worked is an array with three color values. But this leads to polygons of the same color. Why does something simple as `color=np.random.rand(3,num_polygons)` not work?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.,0.,1.,1.])

num_polygons = 2
x = np.random.randn(3,num_polygons)
y = np.random.randn(3,num_polygons)
ax.fill(x,y,color=[0.8,0.3,0.2]) # <--- ??

plt.show()
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score -1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.,0.,1.,1.])

num_polygons = 2
x = np.random.randn(3,num_polygons)
y = np.random.randn(3,num_polygons)
ax.fill(x,y, 'green')

plt.show()
```

Comment: All polygons are green now. I want to draw polygons of different color.